# How to create a field inside a field in a model in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, field

I have model as follows.

I have 4 **choicefields** for people which are (single, couple, family, and group). Users can select any one. But the problem is when the user selects family, he should also select the number of children and no of adults that are going for the trip.

Now, how can I have a field in the model such that, I have 4 choices, but for a family choice, I also need an option to select no of adults and no of children. The same goes for group choice.

**Family pic**
[image: Family pic]

**Single**
[image: Single]

Now my model is:

```
class CustomBooking(models.Model):
    PEOPLE_CHOICES = (
            ('Single', 'Single',),
            ('Couple', 'Couple',),
            ('Family', 'Family',),
            ('Group', 'Group'),
        )
    AGE_GROUP = (
            ('18-35 yrs', '18-35 yrs',),
            ('36-50 yrs', '36-50 yrs',),
            ('51-64 yrs', '51-64 yrs',),
            ('65+ yrs', '65+ yrs',),
        )
    
    people = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=PEOPLE_CHOICES, default='Couple')
    geographical_area = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bookedfor = models.DateField(blank=True)
    age_group = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=AGE_GROUP, default='18-35 yrs')
    
    trip_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = RichTextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created_at',)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the fields and give them a default value.

```
class CustomBooking(models.Model):
    ...
    number_of_children = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    number_of_adults = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: This can work.But is it a right approach?? I mean in my backend CRM, even if I choose Single or Couple, I still can choose no of children or adults which is not what we want.